# Write general $.ajax() function with ability to overwrite success handling

Tags: jquery

The context is: I'm doing ajax calls all over the place for processing forms on my site but generally, they are doing the same sort of thing and showing similar feedback. So I planned to write a function that does validation and an ajax call and then bind that to all forms on my site (with a certain class).

Done that. Works well.

Except.. in those cases where I want to do something slightly different on success.

Is there an elegant way I can leave that function in place but override it on a form by form basis when I need? it's just the success handling I want to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Supply a callback to your ajax call. In your success handler, call this callback.

```
function newAjax(successCallback, errorCallback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: successCallback(),
    error: errorCallback()
  });
}
```

I'd also advise you to check for existence of the callbacks first, so that no error is thrown up when you don't supply both callbacks. Of course, feel free to extend it anyhow you like.

```
function newAjax(successCallback, errorCallback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function() { 
      if (typeof successCallback === "function") {
       successCallback()
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      if (typeof errorCallback === "function") {
       errorCallback()
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You saved my time buddy. Thanks :) How about overriding the "data" values that are part of ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) handler.

> Description: Attach a function to be executed whenever an Ajax request completes successfully

The documentation also provides an example on how to differentiate between requests:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/test.html" ) {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler. The ajax response was: " +
      xhr.responseText );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also can take advantage of the ajaxSetup function. You can use it to set default values for ajax calls, and then you'll have to change the success callback only.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is:

Specify custom callback functions for forms in an attribute of the form element.
Now from the common callback function, check if a specific callback is specified for the current form. If yes, call it with the response as a parameter.

```
<form class="ajax-form" action="some/path" data-submit-callback="loginFormCallback">
</form>
```

//Binding Common callback

```
$(document).on('submit', '.ajax-form', function(){
    $.ajax({url: url, type: type, data: data-from-form}).done(function(response){
    var specialCallback = $(this).attr('data-submit-callback');
    if(specialCallback)
       window[specialCallback](response);
    //common processing goes here
    });
});
```

//Special callback for login form

```
function loginFormCallback(response){
    //do something special for login form here.
}
```